# Hide parent div from child of same parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I want to hide a parent component from a child. What I tried is, I used that component as background with putting additional background to childs to override. But that is don't fit to me in regards to some problems on FrontEnd.

Is it possible to hide child1(when it is absolute, cuz only with absoulte works on my frontend for some design purposes, or if you have suggestion to put an image along fullpage that won't be visible at child3) from child3 when its visible on child2 ?

Thanks for all answers.

```js
<main className="mainbg">
    <div className="child1">
              a component along the page. from top to bottom. see css.
    </div>
    {/*/ <Awesomeslider> /*/}
    <div className="child2">
         firstslide
    </div>
    <div className="child3">
        rightslide
    </div>
    {/*/ <Awesomeslider/> /*/}
</main>

//Slider with React.js = awesomeslider
```

```css
.mainbg {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(/*/ some gradient along the page including sliders /*/);
}
.child1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50vw;              /*/ will be setted as it will be fit along full page from main to child2, but it must be hidden in child3 /*/
    margin: auto;
}
.child2 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;            /*/ child1 will be visible here /*/
}

.child3 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;              /*/ child1 won't be visible here /*/
}
```

```html
<div id="root"><div/>
```

Additional Draft:

https://i.ibb.co/1Jss5R5/photo-2022-10-20-04-59-33.jpg

Comment: Do you want to create a carousel?

Comment: Not actually, its gonna be fullpage slider including backend and frontend inside

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index: -1` on those who has to be hidden and add `z-index: 1` to the one which has to be show.

NOTE: `z-index` will only work of that element has `position: ANY_POSITION` applied to that.

Comment: I just tried, When adding z-index -1, its just dissappearing from whole page, I tried to also add z-index -1 to main to show that component on main and don't show at child3 with index 1. There is some other zindex on parents I guess lemme check again.

Comment: After check, nope it not fits, I still can see the component on zindex1

Comment: Can we hide an element from parent on child on css ? Like: .parent> .child3 { visibility:hidden }

Comment: I need a solution based on Javascript I guess